# Display multiple random divs on click

Tags: javascript, random

Hoping someone can help with this...

I am trying to set up a page to randomly display Div content from several Div blocks onClick. I have some base code I found and have been playing with but I can't work out how to modify it to display multiple Divs at once.

```js
var random = document.getElementsByClassName('random')[0];
var menuCovers = document.getElementsByClassName('menu_cover2');

function openRandomMenu() {

  for (var i = 0; i < menuCovers.length; i++) {

    if (menuCovers[i].classList.contains('visible')) {
      var skip = i;
      menuCovers[i].classList.remove('visible');
      menuCovers[i].classList.add('invisible');
    }
  }

  var randomNumber = skip;

  while (randomNumber === skip) {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * menuCovers.length);
  }

  menuCovers[randomNumber].classList.remove('invisible');
  menuCovers[randomNumber].classList.add('visible');
}

random.addEventListener('click', openRandomMenu, false);
```

```css
.visible {
  display: block;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}

.bloc {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.offset {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="random bloc">Random</p>
  <div class="menu_cover invisible bloc">One</div>
  <div class="menu_cover invisible bloc">Menu two</div>
  <div class="menu_cover invisible bloc">Menu three</div>
  <div class="menu_cover invisible bloc">Menu four</div>
  <div class="menu_cover invisible bloc">Menu five</div>
  <div class="menu_cover invisible bloc">Menu six</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 invisible bloc offset">Menu Xone</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 invisible bloc offset">Menu Xtwo</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 invisible bloc offset">Menu Xthree</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 invisible bloc offset">Menu Xfour</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 invisible bloc offset">Menu Xfive</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 invisible bloc offset">Menu Xsix</div>
</div>
```

With the above, as per the original example, I can get one of the Div blocks to display, in this case 'menu_cover2' but not the first.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Nowhere in your code there's a try to cache the `".menu_cover"` elements and any attempt to perform any action on them. You only use `var menuCovers = document.getElementsByClassName('menu_cover2');`. Also `.visible` is not needed. Pure logic, you only need to toggle one class, not two. One are the default element styles (noo special class needed) and then you need to only toggle the `.invisible` one using the classList.toggle() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

I am assuming the two sets have the same number of divs

```js
const randomNumbers = (n, min, max) => Array.from({ length: n }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));

const covers = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_cover");
const covers2 = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_cover2");

document.querySelector('.random')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    covers.forEach(cover => cover.hidden = true);
    covers2.forEach(cover => cover.hidden = true);
    const arr = randomNumbers(2, 0, covers.length-1);
    covers[arr[0]].hidden = false;
    covers2[arr[1]].hidden = false;
  });
```

```css
.bloc {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.offset {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="random bloc">Random</p>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu One</div>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu two</div>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu three</div>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu four</div>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu five</div>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu six</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 bloc offset" hidden>Menu Xone</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 bloc offset" hidden>Menu Xtwo</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 bloc offset" hidden>Menu Xthree</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 bloc offset" hidden>Menu Xfour</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 bloc offset" hidden>Menu Xfive</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 bloc offset" hidden>Menu Xsix</div>
</div>
```

If the list of divs is of different length we can do this

```js
const randomNumber = (len) => Math.floor(Math.random() * len);

const covers = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_cover");
const covers2 = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_cover2");

document.querySelector('.random')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    covers.forEach(cover => cover.hidden = true);
    covers2.forEach(cover => cover.hidden = true);
    const ran = randomNumber(covers.length);
    const ran2 = randomNumber(covers2.length);
    covers[ran].hidden = false;
    covers2[ran2].hidden = false;
  });
```

```css
.bloc {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.offset {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="random bloc">Random</p>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu One</div>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu two</div>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu three</div>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu four</div>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu five</div>
  <div class="menu_cover bloc" hidden>Menu six</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 bloc offset" hidden>Menu Xone</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 bloc offset" hidden>Menu Xtwo</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 bloc offset" hidden>Menu Xthree</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually is perfect as it does address the one thing I forgot about, which is different lengths! Thanks so much, I can def run with this as a solution!

Answer (score 0):

- No need for the `.visible` rule. Also, use rather a `.is-hidden` instead of `.invisible` (which would imply *visibility:hidden* instead of *display:none* )
- use `Element.classList.toggle("is-hidden", boolean)` on both your sets
- create a reusable function `rand(min, max)` that returns a float random number in range `0, NodeList.length`, and then use `Math.floor(rn)` or `~~rn` to round it down
- use `<button>` is something should be a user-action element, not `<p>`

```js
// DOM helpers, utils:
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

// Task: toggle random menu covers:
const elRandom = el(".random");
const elsCover1 = els(".menu_cover");
const elsCover2 = els(".menu_cover2");

const openRandomMenu = () => {
  const r1 = Math.floor(rand(0, elsCover1.length));
  const r2 = Math.floor(rand(0, elsCover2.length));
  elsCover1.forEach((elC1, i) => elC1.classList.toggle("is-hidden", i !== r1));
  elsCover2.forEach((elC2, i) => elC2.classList.toggle("is-hidden", i !== r2));
}

elRandom.addEventListener('click', openRandomMenu, false);
```

```css
.blocks > * {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <button class="random" type="button">Random</button>
  <div class="menu_cover is-hidden">Menu one</div>
  <div class="menu_cover is-hidden">Menu two</div>
  <div class="menu_cover is-hidden">Menu three</div>
  <div class="menu_cover is-hidden">Menu four</div>
  <div class="menu_cover is-hidden">Menu five</div>
  <div class="menu_cover is-hidden">Menu six</div>
</div>

<div class="blocks offset">
  <div class="menu_cover2 is-hidden">Menu Xone</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 is-hidden">Menu Xtwo</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 is-hidden">Menu Xthree</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 is-hidden">Menu Xfour</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 is-hidden">Menu Xfive</div>
  <div class="menu_cover2 is-hidden">Menu Xsix</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great and works a treat. mplungjan's solution below though addressed the one thing I forgot about with is different lengths of lists. Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: @IAGT my answer also addresses different lists length out of the box. You're very welcome

Comment: What is `par` in your querySelector(All) replacement?

Comment: @Roco C. Buljan, so it does! I'll now have to weight them up :) Cheers!!

Comment: @IAGT `par` is for when you don't want to use the default `document` in `document.querySelector(selector)` but rather `someParentElement.querySelector(slector)` which is way faster and limits the DOM search - in such case you pass it as argument: `const elMenu = el("#menu"); const elsList = els("li", elMenu);` - now only those `<li>` elements inside `<ul id="menu">` are in your collection instead of all the LIs in the document. Obviously you can also use `const elsList = els("#menu li");` - but it's often really useful. Hope it makes sense. I use those utils helpers all the time ;)